# What is the difference between 'couriers tasks' and 'courier tasks'?

Tags: difference, compound-nouns

What is the difference between 'couriers tasks' and 'courier tasks'?

And could anybody say a topic where I can research this question?

The second is a compound noun but the first...

Comment: **Couriers' tasks** or **a/the courier's tasks** makes sense with a possessive apostrophe; otherwise, it's hard to see how it can be used.. Giving us the source of your question may assist us to answer it.

Comment: I want to name a database table and started thinking about what is difference between couriers_tasks and courier_tasks. And in general, can I name it like 'couriers_tasks' in my opinion it's not correct but I've already seen this variant.

Comment: Two thoughts: You can assign whatever names you wish to tables. They don't have to be grammatical. AND Having seen a variant is no guarantee that it is grammatical. But my comment remains true, that it's hard to understand what **couriers tasks** refers to.

Comment: The table of 'couriers_tasks' refers to tasks that are assigned to couriers. I just want to be sure that the both can be used and I will have not another meaning)
Thanks!

Comment: No, I do not think that they will have another meaning.